# Factory method design patterns

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I am new to design patterns. I am trying to use factory method design pattern in my current application. In the application i have two groups(i.e group1 and group2) and each group will have different methods. Is it good practice to use application roles as classes and inherit from product(i.e group2). Can anyone tell me whether following sample code is right or wrong.

```
class Creator
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args[0] == "GroupHead")
        {
            IGroup2 gh = new GroupHead();
        }
        else if (args[0] == "ProjectIncharge")
        {
            IGroup2 gh = new ProjectIncharge();
        }
    }
}


interface IGroup1
{
    List<Employee> GetEmployees();
}

interface IGroup2
{
    List<Projects> GetProjects();
}

public class Group : IGroup1
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        //Code here
    }
}

public class GroupHead : IGroup2
{
    public List<Projects> GetProjects()
    {
        //Code here
    }
}

public class ProjectIncharge : IGroup2
{
    public List<Projects> GetProjects()
    {
        //Code here
    }
}

public class ProjectManager : IGroup2
{
    public List<Projects> GetProjects()
    {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a way of doing it... However I think you're conflating the person with the role. I.e. a person could be both a ProjectManager and a GroupHead. If you haven't already done so, try taking a look at [.NET's role-based security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b3sz1a.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pattern to do this its return to initialize object according to searchoption.

```
        interface IGroup2
        {
            string SearchOption { get; set; }
            List<Projects> GetProjects();
        }

        public class GroupHead : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public GroupHead()
            {
                SearchOption = "GroupHead";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {   
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class ProjectIncharge : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public ProjectIncharge()
            {
                SearchOption = "ProjectIncharge";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class ProjectManager : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public ProjectManager()
            {
                SearchOption = "ProjectManager";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

public class Test
{
        private static List<IGroup2> searchRuleList = new List<IGroup2>()
        {
          new GroupHead(),
          new ProjectIncharge(),
          new ProjectManager(),
        };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         IGroup2 searchOptionRule = searchRuleList.Find(delegate(IGroup2 searchRule) { return searchRule.SearchOption.Equals(args[0]); });

        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it right approach to use roles as classes inheriting from group2 or is there any other approach to use factory method instead of using roles as classes.

Comment: some how you should keep the track of mappin of concrete implimentaion.